# Symfony 5 Doctrine ORM getting data form manytomany relations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I am trying to learn Symfony 5 and within the course I am doing there is a Doctrine ORM section.
One chapter is relationships. I am stuck with MantToMany relationship.

This is the example he uses in the course.

There is a user table referencing to itself to store which user is following which user. In the user entity there is followed and following with all setters and getters.

With the migration in the database there was a new table created users_users.
This is all clear to me and makes sense.

Within my defaultController I get user with the id of 12:

```
$user1 = $userRep->find(12);
```

In his example in the course he shows how to get the number of the followers of user1 by

```
$user1->getFollowed()->count();
```

But only states that one can get other data of the followed users also and goes on to the next lecture. 
I now try to figure out how to get e. g. the names of the followed users.
To be honest I don't even know where to start looking.

I googled Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection since I found out that count() is a part of it, but it didn't help me.

Can someone push me in the right direction? I don't want to start the next lecture of this course if I am not able to grasp this.

Thanks!

Comment: A [`Collection`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/index.html) is an `Iterable` object of a type, you can think of it as `User[]`, so you can `foreach($user->getFollowed() as $followed) $followed->getName();`. You can also do other operations as `filter`, `map`, etc.

Comment: It's that simple? And I thought I have to learn all the methods in the collection.
Thank you very much! It worked and now I can go on with this course.

Comment: Well, you can do many operations, specially the `Selectable` interface is quite powerful, but unless you are working with other type of `Collection` instead of `PersistentCollection` (like an `ArrayCollection`) it's quite likely that you'll use `Repository` or `Query` methods. They can be handy, so have a once over, but they might appear in more advanced chapters.